# how to sort array of pairs and access by iterator

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have array lp ,in lp we have pairs (loop,index), loop is number of loop for each car and index is car Example (4,2) mean car number 2 is in 4th loop I want sort lp by number of loops I have goal array that give score to each car by compare loops

BY java scripts I want push some pairs in array then sort this array By first value Of Pairs
and I want access this pairs With index , like arrays (not like keys value)

imagine I want for calculate rank cars in racing cars ,to pair loops of each car to car's index  then add to array and sort array. then I want Give score To these cars who is first with maximum loop gain max score
order is Too important for this code (in Unity)
i can write it with c++ (use pair+ set+ iterator)

Comment: You have a bunch of questions here. Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: Well... you want push objects (key, value) into array, and then sort it by key? if so... you can try something like this... `var myArr = []; myArr.push({0 : "some Value"}); /* and etc. */ myArr.sort(function (a, b) { return a[Object.keys(a)[0]] - b[Object.keys(b)[0]]; }); /* I have not tested it, but seems, it should work ... */`

Comment: @Givi, it might be better for you to post your comment as an answer instead.

Comment: @jrd1 The question is not quite clear, and it is doubtful whether my answer will be better...

Comment: I  have array lp ,in lp we have pairs (loop,index), loop is  number of loop  for each car and index is car 
Example  (4,2) mean car number 2 is in 4th loop
I want sort lp by number of loops
I  have goal array that give score to each car by compare loops,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to do, but if you want push objects (key : value) into an array, and then sort it by key, you can try something like this...
[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/ZqtBa/)

```
var myArr = [];
myArr.push({
    0: "some Value"
});
myArr.push({
    2: "some Value2"
});
myArr.push({
    1: "some Value1"
});
myArr.push({
    6: "some Value6"
});
myArr.push({
    5: "some Value5"
});
myArr.push({
    3: "some Value3"
});
myArr.push({
    4: "some Value4"
});
/* and etc. */
myArr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return Object.keys(a)[0] - Object.keys(b)[0];
});

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    for (var prop in myArr[i]) {
        if (myArr[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            console.log(prop);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is order of this algorithm?